# How do you escape a completionBlock in Swift to return to normal application flow?

Tags: swift, completionhandler

One of the things that's throwing me in Swift is the never-ending chain of `completionBlocks` in my program; and I'm not sure how to get Swift to say *"Ok, the completion block is now done -- come back to the main program."*

In my project  I am writing a simple board/card game which loads its data from a very small plist.

I wrote a fairly simple Plist loader, it loads the plist and kicks back `Data` via a completionBlock.   It doesn't do any parsing; it doesn't care about how you want to parse it, it simply returns `NSData` (`Data`) or errors.

I have a `Parser` which fires the Plist loader, gets the `Data` and then parses it using the new Swift `Codable` protocol.

```
// A static function to try and find the plist file on bundle, load it and pass back data
static func loadBoard(completionHandler: @escaping (Board?, Error?) -> Void) {
     PListFileLoader.getDataFrom(filename: "data.plist") { (data, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print ("errors found")
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
            else {
                guard let hasData = data else {
                    print ("no data found")
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                    return
                }
                do {
                    print ("found board")
                    let board = try decodeBoard(from: hasData) // Call a function that will use the decoder protocol 
                    completionHandler(board, nil)
                } catch {
                    print ("some other board error occured")
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

and then returns this parsed data to the main program, or whatever called it -- for example; an `XCTest`

My XCTest:

```
func testBoardDidLoad() -> Board? {   // The return bit will show an error; but its fine without the return part
        BoardParsePlist.loadBoard { (board, error)  in
            XCTAssertNotNil(board, "Board is nil")
            XCTAssertNotNil(error, error.debugDescription)

// How do I now escape this and return flow to the normal application?
// Can I wrap this in a try-catch?
            }
        }
```

From a hierarchical view it sort of looks like this.

```
XCTest
... Calls the parser  (completionBlock ...)
.... Parser calls the PListLoader  (completionHandler: ...)
```

Now it feels like I'm stuck in the block for the rest of the app

```
BoardParsePlist.loadBoard { (board, error)  in
      // ... rest of the app now lives here?    
})
```

It seems I'm in a never ending loop of `completionBlock`s.

How do you "escape" or break out of the completion block and return flow back to the main app?

I'm not sure if I explained it correctly, but would appreciate any assistance on this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not sure how to get Swift to say "Ok, the completion block is now done -- come back to the main program."

There's no way and no need to say that - it happens automatically.

```
static func loadBoard(completionHandler: @escaping (Board?, Error?) -> Void) {
     PListFileLoader.getDataFrom(filename: "data.plist") { (data, error) in
          // completion handler code here
     }

     // "back to main"
}
```

In your example, execution will get "back to main" in one of two ways, depending on whether `PListFileLoader.getDataFrom` is running asynchronously or not.

If it's running synchronously, the execution order will be:

- your app calls `loadBoard`
- this calls `getDataFrom`
- which in turn calls its completion handler parameter
- the completion handler runs
- "back to main" runs

OTOH, if `getDataFrom` is asynchronous (e.g. because it does a network request), the order will be:

- your app calls `loadBoard`
- this calls `getDataFrom`
- which starts its asynchronous work and returns
- "back to main" runs
- at some later point in time, the work started by `getDataFrom` is done, and it calls the completion handler parameter
- the completion handler runs

Either way, you get back to main without special effort.

Comment: Thanks for your help.   I think the issue was I was using it in a XCTest and wanted to load the plist once and only once so I didn't have to recreate it in memory each time for each test and my "concept" was to have one function to load the board in memory and then pass it to each XCTestCase I needed.   But now I understand the reaosning now, and appreciate the assistance